# Play framework external Javascript URL syntax

Tags: javascript, playframework

How to use external JavaScript files in the Play framework?

I used this syntax:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I put this in the `<head>` section of `main.scala.html`.

`https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js` is the correct link, but it doesn't load and the status of the package is `(blocked:csp)`:

[image: Status (blocked:csp) (picture1)]

Headers:

[image: Package header (picture2)]

Local javascript files work fine, for example:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/hello.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSP stands for **Content Security Policy** ([see more](https://content-security-policy.com/)): 
The corresponding header defines from which sources certain components are allowed to be loaded. Usually, the default settings is `default-src: 'self'`. Than means only your own host is allowed as source for scripts, css, images, etc. In your case that was `localhost:9999`, so your local javascript file was passed. You will need to add `gstatic.com` as an allowed `script-src`. 
Thus, this configuration needs to be done in your `application.conf`-file:

```
play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src: 'self'; script-src: 'self' gstatic.com"
```

For further information, please visit the [official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SecurityHeaders).

Comment: More recent versions seem to require directives without the colons. For example I had console errors in Chrome 65 and Safari 11 when I used the above example which was fixed after I changed it to `default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' gstatic.com`.